# Descobrir elementos comuns em várias listas

Tags: python

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
list1 = ['a', 'x', 'c', 'b', 'm']
list2 = ['f', 'x', 'a', 'c']
list3 = ['c', 'e', 'x', 'b', 'p', 'k', 'l']
```

Como descubro os elementos comuns, de maneira a que fique com uma lista assim:

```
comuns = ['x', 'c']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode usar sets e fazer a interseção entre eles, sets são vulgarmente usados para proibir valores duplicados em uma lista, se quiser remover valores repetidos transforme a sua lista num set (`set(minha_lista)`). Mas para neste caso também é para nos permitir que usemos a função `intersection` (`&`), tal como faço em baixo. Para declarar um set sintaticamente é como faz com um dicionário mas sem atribuir valores às chaves (`meu_set = {1,2,3}`). Usar sets neste tipo de operações é significativamente mais rápido do que do que faze-las diretamente em listas ou dicts.

Note que os ultimos dois exemplos é para entender a lógica, não use em projetos reais, exatamente por ser mais custoso, lento, especialmente em grandes quantidades de dados.

Faça assim:

```
comuns = list(set(list1) & set(list2) & set(list3)) # ['x', 'c']
```

Ou:

```
comuns = list(set(list1).intersection(list2).intersection(list3)) # ['x', 'c']
```

'Manualmente' também daria com as estruturas normais (não recomendo):

```
comuns = []
for i in list1:
    if(i in list2 and i in list3):
        comuns.append(i)

# comuns = ['x', 'c']
```

Que usando list compreension ficaria (não recomendo):

```
comuns = [i for i in list1 if(i in list2 and i in list3)]

# comuns = ['x', 'c']
```

Comment: Sim - mas usar os `sets` conjuntos é muito mais eficiente, sobretudo para listas grandes - a resposta está bem correta, ma sachoque você podia acrescentar alguma coisa sobre os `set`s: o que sõa, como funcioname  como diferem de listas, além de dar a resposta pronta.

Comment: Vou fazer  isso @jsbueno